# Python tabulate TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable over object

Tags: python

I'm attempting to make use of the python library `tabulate` to convert the beneath object to a table.

```
count = {
"George": 1,
"John": 2
}
```

With the simple py line shown beneath

```
amount = tabulate(count, tablefmt='html', headers=["User","Amount Issued"])
```

However, I'm recieving the error:

```
Result: Failure
Exception: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

My novice programming knowledge is telling me that the integers as values are not expected.

I assumed this line would generate:

| User | Amount Issued |
| --- | --- |
| George | 1 |
| John | 2 |

I'm not sure how to convert the object values to type string without iterating through the values using a for loop and thought this was not the best method of doing so.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a snippet that worked for me!

```
count = [
    {
        "user": "George",
        "amount_issued": 1
    }, {
        "user": "John",
        "amount_issued": 2
    }
]

amount = tabulate(count, tablefmt='html', headers={"User": "", "Amount Issued": ""})
```

It gives error because he finds an inconsistency between the `count` data type (dict) and the `header` data type (array).

I think this solution is more readable, since John and George are technically two objects, but you could also try with:

```
count = [["George", 1], ["John", 2]]

amount = tabulate(count, tablefmt='html', headers=["User","Amount Issued"])
```

Where count is an array of arrays! It just depends on which of these is your easiest way to retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

When using a `dict` headers are the keys, so you would need something like

```
count = {
    "User": ["George", "John"],
    "Amount Issued": [1, 2]
}
```